# Show that the set of positive integers less than and coprime to 21 form a group with respect to multiplication modulo 21.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that this group is isomorphic to $H \times K$, where $H$ and $K$ are cyclic groups of orders $6$ and $2$, respectively. Help!

Comment: Concerning your title -the units of a commutative ring form a group. In particular $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ is a group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde   You would can show it unused ring-theory?

Comment: You can show this without ring theory. For $n=21$ you can just write it down directly. But this is not your question, it seems. It is only in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p,q$ be different primes. Then we have the ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/pq\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\times \mathbb{Z}/q$, so that, for the unit groups
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/pq)^*\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p)^*\times (\mathbb{Z}/q)^*\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\times \mathbb{Z}/(q-1)
$$
For $p=3$ and $q=7$ we have $p-1=2$ and $q-1=6$, hence the result, i.e.,
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/21)^*\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/6.
$$